# Poor speed of ConnectSystemModelComponents and CreateSystemModel

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning, system-modeler

I'm trying to use `SystemModel` to simulate a large air conditioning system, but my kernel crashes from time to time when I try to connect my custom models with each other. Even if the kernel does not crash, the `ConnectSystemModelComponents` takes more than an hour on my laptop. To show the problem, here is a simple example.

```
SystemModel; (* initialization *)
$NoModel = 200;
AbsoluteTiming[Table[model[i] = 
  CreateSystemModel[
   "MP.Model_" <> ToString[i], {y[tau] == x[tau] + 0.5 i}, 
   tau, {x \[Element] "RealInput", y \[Element] "RealOutput"}], {i, 1, $NoModel}];]
(* {124.184, Null} *)

components = 
  Table[("m_" <> ToString[i]) \[Element] ("MP.Model_" <> ToString[i]), {i, 1, $NoModel}];
connections = 
  Table[("m_" <> ToString[i] <> ".y") -> ("m_" <> ToString[i + 1] <> ".x"), {i, 1, $NoModel - 1}];

mmu = MaxMemoryUsed[];
AbsoluteTiming[
 system = ConnectSystemModelComponents["MP.Conn", components, 
    connections];]
MaxMemoryUsed[] - mmu
(* {86.7367, Null} *)
(* 25348136 *)
```

Any idea how to accelerate `CreateSystemModel` and `ConnectSystemModelComponents`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By playing back and forth, I found a quick and dirty answer. It seems that the function `ConnectSystemModelComponents` has an undocumented option `GraphLayout`. Setting it to `None` will save a huge amount of time, which leads to my guess that `ConnectSystemModelComponents` spends most of the time arranging the positions of the model and connection graphics. Since I do not have SystemModeler or other Modelica graphical interfaces, graphics are not major concern to me.

```
(*initialization*)$NoModel = 100;
AbsoluteTiming[
 Table[model[i] = 
    CreateSystemModel[
     "MP.Model_" <> ToString[i], {y[tau] == x[tau] + 0.5 i}, 
     tau, {x \[Element] "RealInput", y \[Element] "RealOutput"}], {i, 
    1, $NoModel}];]
(* {42.924, Null} *)

components = 
  Join[{"x" \[Element] CreateDataSystemModel[0 &, 0, 1000], 
    "y" \[Element] "RealOutput"}, 
   Table[("m_" <> ToString[i]) \[Element] ("MP.Model_" <> 
       ToString[i]), {i, 1, $NoModel}]];
connections = 
  Join[{"x.y[1]" -> "m_1.x", 
    "y" -> "m_" <> ToString[$NoModel] <> ".y"}, 
   Table[("m_" <> ToString[i] <> ".y") -> ("m_" <> ToString[i + 1] <> 
       ".x"), {i, 1, $NoModel - 1}]];

mmu = MaxMemoryUsed[];
AbsoluteTiming[
 system = ConnectSystemModelComponents["MP.Conn", components, 
    connections, GraphLayout -> None];]
MaxMemoryUsed[] - mmu
(* {2.04898, Null} *)
(* 0 *)
```

Comment: This is correct, a lot of the time in creating models with ConnectSystemModelComponents is spent layouting the diagram of the model. `GraphLayout -> None` is a great workaround if you don't care about the graphical parts of the model. It is even documented: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConnectSystemModelComponents.html#944144882